# Beating O(n!) for computing joint distributions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, probability-density

I have `n` normal distributions of varying means and standard deviations (some distributions do have the same standard deviations)

My goal is to compute the expected rank of the populations in each distribution.

One approach I came up with was subtracting each distribution from each other one then finding the proportion of the new distribution that was > 0. Doing this allowed me to populate a nxn matrix (where `P(i>j)` indicates the probability that distribution i is greater than distribution j):

```
   0   | P(1>2) | P(1>3) .... P(1>n)
P(2>1) |    0   | P(2>3) .... P(2>n)
....
P(n>1) | P(n>2) | P(n>3) ....   0
```

But to compute the expected ranks I still had to do the following, where `P(dist i, rank r)` means the probability that a sample from distribution i is rank r eg. `P(dist1, rank1)` would mean the probability that a sample from distribution 1 is the first place winner/highest rank:

```
P(dist1,rank1) = P(1>2) & ... & P(1>n)
P(dist1,rank2) =
    P(1<2) & P(1>3) & ... & P(1>n) |
    P(1>2) & P(1<3) & ... & P(1>n) |
    ...
    P(1>n) & P(1<2) & ... & P(1>n-1)
P(dist1, rank3) = ...
P(dist2, rank...)
....
```

Which gives me n! time (I routinely have ~150-200 distributions) so n! isn't feasible.

I'd like to avoid solutions that involve sampling the distributions if at all possible, but if that isn't possible any readings/papers that explain why it isn't an/ or offer robust sampling methods would be helpful

My desired result is for each of n distributions given m ranks I have the following:

```
P(dist1, rank1) | P(dist1, rank2) | ... | P(dist1, rankm)
...
P(distn, rank1) | P(distn, rank2) | ... | P(distn, rankm)
```

Said another way; if I were to sample the distributions what would the probability be that for a given distribution their sample(s) would be ranked highest? lowest? or each rank between?

Assuming I know the true mean and standard deviation for each distribution, how can I compute the probability that a given distribution's sample will be of rank n (time complexity comes in since I'm interested in knowing the probabilities for each rank for each distribution)

Comment: It seems like the topic you're looking for is called "order statistics". A better forum for such a question is stats.stackexchange.com. You might consider adjusting your notation; I don't think people will generally understand what you mean by P(disti, rankj) so you might want to try to clarify that.

Comment: Great, that helps. This question is interesting but definitely beyond the scope of SO and more suitable for stats.SE. When you repost there, you might want to clarify whether you have a sample of n values, one from each distribution; that's what it sounds like. If that's the case, you might want to make it more explicit, and if it's not, you might want to say exactly how the sampling works.

Comment: Thanks again Robert, I'll repost there -- my goal is to avoid sampling all together and compute the probabilities directly

Comment: Understood, however, the solution is probably going to depend on just how it's phrased conceptually, so it helps to explicitly state that stuff.

Comment: I think you may have missed the line `I'd like to avoid solutions that involve sampling the distributions if at all possible, but if it isn't reading that highlights that would be useful` if not -- how could I make it clearer? -- I'm missing a little punctuation

Comment: From that I assume you mean that you want to avoid Monte Carlo solutions and instead seek an algebraic result -- that makes a lot of sense (although, a minor quibble, I'm not sure what you mean to say "but if it isn't reading that highlights that would be useful"). When I ask about sampling one item from each distribution or what, I mean, how are you framing the question conceptually. Are you imagining that you are drawing one item from each distribution and then asking what's the expected value of the rank of the k'th item, or something else? This is the point that I'm suggesting you clarify.

Comment: Great -- updated that line, I think the missing punctuation made it unclear.

So I'm assuming I know the true mean and standard deviation; I'm looking to understand given the n distributions if I sampled them what is the probability that for any one distribution their sample(s) would be in rank 1, 2, ... n